# Breaking down using set notation, conditional probability

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

Assuming B is given as already having happened, and you have sets A and C:

$$ P(A \cup C \mid B) = P(A \mid B) + P(C \mid B) - P(A \cap C \mid B)$$

In the case of conditional probabiltiy, when an event has already occurred, in this case B, when breaking down two given events (ex. A or B), can the "given" event be distributed as shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability),

$P(A \cup C | B) = \dfrac{P((A \cup C) \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

From basic [set theory](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_Distributes_over_Union) and the ["sum rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) we derive the following expression for the numerator:

$ P((A \cup C) \cap B) = P((A \cap B) \cup (C \cap B)) = P(A \cap B) + P(C \cap B) - P(A \cap C \cap B)$.

Dividing by $P(B)$ gives the desired result.